# Click on camera shutter button is not responding

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, ui-automation

I am using xamarin UI to automate my mobile application

I came across camera shutter button where I need click on shutter button and take some picture

I validated shutter button exist or not (passed)

I tried using App.Tap(“shutter”)
It did not respond and throws unable to find query

Any answer will help fix the issue.